# "non-finite function value" when using integrate() in R

Tags: r

I am using the following R code, taken from a published paper (citation below).  This is the code:

```
int2=function(x,r,n,p) {
    (1+x)^((n-1-p)/2)*(1+(1-r^2)*x)^(-(n-1)/2)*x^(-3/2)*exp(-n/(2*x))}
integrate(f=int2,lower=0,upper=Inf,n=530,r=sqrt(.245),p=3, stop.on.error=FALSE)
```

When I run it, I get the error "non-finite function value". Yet Maple is able to compute this as 4.046018765*10^27.

I tried using "integral" in package pracma, which gives me a different error:
Error in if (delta < tol) break : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

The overall goal is to compute a ratio of two integrals, as described in Wetzels & Wagenmakers (2012) "A default Bayesian hypothesis test for correlations" (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3505519/).  The entire function is as follows:

```
jzs.pcorbf = function(r0, r1, p0, p1, n) {
  int = function(r,n,p,g) {
    (1+g)^((n-1-p)/2)*(1+(1-r^2)*g)^(-(n-1)/2)*g^(-3/2)*exp(-n/(2*g))};
  bf10=integrate(int, lower=0,upper=Inf,r=r1,p=p1,n=n)$value/
       integrate(int,lower=0,upper=Inf,r=r0,p=p0,n=n)$value;
  return(bf10)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: missing or `NaN` input values are considered as non-finite.

Comment: I don't think that is it.  There are no missing or NaN input values.  There is no data.  It's the integration of a simple mathematical expression.

Comment: That's not a good way of looking at it, Dimitri: numerical integration *does* use "data," as it has to calculate the value of the integrand at a specified number of locations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that your integral function is generating `NaN` values when called with `x` values in its domain. You're integrating from 0 to `Infinity`, so let's check a valid `x` value of 1000:

```
int2(1000, sqrt(0.245), 530, 3)
# [1] NaN
```

Your objective multiplies four pieces:

```
x <- 1000
r <- sqrt(0.245)
n <- 530
p <- 3
(1+x)^((n-1-p)/2)
# [1] Inf
(1+(1-r^2)*x)^(-(n-1)/2)
# [1] 0
x^(-3/2)
# [1] 3.162278e-05
exp(-n/(2*x))
# [1] 0.7672059
```

We can now see that the issue is that you're multiplying infinity by 0 (or rather something numerically equal to infinity times something numerically equal to 0), which is causing the numerical issues. Instead of calculating `a*b*c*d`, it will be more stable to calculate `exp(log(a) + log(b) + log(c) + log(d))` (using the identity that `log(a*b*c*d) = log(a)+log(b)+log(c)+log(d)`). One other quick note -- the value x=0 needs a special case.

```
int3 = function(x, r, n, p) {
  loga <- ((n-1-p)/2) * log(1+x)
  logb <- (-(n-1)/2) * log(1+(1-r^2)*x)
  logc <- -3/2 * log(x)
  logd <- -n/(2*x)
  return(ifelse(x == 0, 0, exp(loga + logb + logc + logd)))
}
integrate(f=int3,lower=0,upper=Inf,n=530,r=sqrt(.245),p=3, stop.on.error=FALSE)
# 1.553185e+27 with absolute error < 2.6e+18
```